# rich text editor with maths equation , record/Upload media and drawing tool

Tags: html, asp.net

i'm looking for a rich text editor with maths equation , record/Upload media and drawing tool, to add it to my website.

Do you know some tools available in internet(free or comercial)?

i heard about CKeditor, TinyMCE , but seems that they don't have all those features.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wiris if you need it for asp.net. Otherwise you may opt for MathML or if your site is a Wordpress blog, then also the Jetpack plugin may be an option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as far as i know , Wiris is only for Maths equation. the good thing is that, i can add it to ckeditor or TinyMce, but i'm still searching a way to add record media and drawing tools